# Vectorizing operations efficiently using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for an efficient NumPy implementation for the following:

My inputs are:

```
X = 2d NumPy array of shape (m,3) (m can be anywhere from 10 to 10 Million)
Q = 2d NumPy array with shape (n,p). Both n and p are small (<= 10)
```

It is easier to explain what I'm looking for using the following example.

Example:

```
X = np.array([[2, 56, 20], [3, 194, 18], [4, 36, 6], [5, 168, 42]]) with m = 4
Q = np.array([[3, 7, 11], [5, 13, 17]]) with n = 2 and p = 3
```

For each row `j` of `X`, I want to find all the rows of `Q` that contain an entry `q` such that `X[j,1]%q == X[j,2]%q`. For the above example, `X[0,1]%q == X[0,2]%q` for `q = 3`, which is in row `0` of `Q`. Similarly, `X[2,1]%q == X[2,2]%q` for `q = 3` and `q = 5`, which are in rows `0` and `1` of `Q`. The output should be list of lists/NumPy arrays with matching rows of `Q` for each row of `X`. For the above example, the output should be: `[[0], [0], [0,1], [0]]`

I have written the following code, but am wondering if there is a more efficient approach.

```
result = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    result.append(np.where(X[i,1] % Q == X[i,2] % Q)[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This computes all modulo combinations at once:

```py
P = X[:, 1:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] % Q
```

The output shape will be [m, 2, n, p]. Note: If you can, change the integer size to i4 or u4 as 32 bit modulo is faster than 64 bit; or go even smaller. It also limits memory consumption which may be significant here.

Now we can do all comparisons at once:

```py
B = P[:, 0] == P[:, 1]
```

The output shape will be [m, n, p]

To find the rows where a suitable q exists, we use `np.any`

```py
F = np.any(B, axis=-1)
```

The shape will be [m, n], for each combination of X and Q, a boolean whether any q in Q matches the row in X.

To get the indices, use `np.nonzero`

```py
Xs, Qs = np.nonzero(F)

for x, q in zip(Xs, Qs):
    print("X index %d matches Q index %d" % (x, q))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I used sets because for sets no duplicates allowed, but for lists they are allowed.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[2, 56, 20], [3, 194, 18], [4, 36, 6], [5, 168, 42]])
Q = np.array([[3, 7, 11], [5, 13, 17]])
    
result = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(Q)):
        v1 = Q[j]
        for k in range(len(Q[j])):
            v2 = v1[k]
            if X[i, 1] % v2 == X[i, 2] % v2:
                temp.append(j)
    result.append(set(temp))

result = np.array(result, dtype=object)
print(result)
```