# Vectorizing a series of operations using NumPy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, performance, multidimensional-array

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73525564/vectorizing-operations-efficiently-using-numpy), I am looking for an efficient implementation of a series of operations using NumPy.

**Problem inputs:**

```
 X - An (n,2) matrix, where the second column is a categorical variable (takes values in 0,1,...,M, for some M <= 10)
 Q - A matrix with random numbers, with number of rows same as the number of categories in X and number of columns <= 10
 R - A character array of length p 
 S - An array of strings with the length = number of categories in X
 j - An index (with zero indexing)
```

The dimensions `n` and `p` can be fairly large, with `1 <= n, p <= 10 million`

**Example inputs:**

```
X = np.array([[2, 0], [4, 0], [5, 1], [5, 0], [3, 1]])  # (two categories: 0,1)
Q = np.array([[3,7,13,11], [19,23,31,29]] )
R = np.array(['a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'f'])
S = np.array(['aacbbc', 'cabbca'])  # (same number of strings as categories)
j = 3
```

**I want an efficient way to compute the following result:**

```
result = [[X[k,0],np.random.choice(Q[X[k,1]])] for k in range(len(X)) if R[X[k,0]] == S[X[k,1]][j]]
```

An example result would be result = [[2, 7], [4, 3], [3, 29]].

**My attempt for a more efficient solution using NumPy:**

```
X = np.array([[2, 0], [4, 0], [5, 1], [5, 0], [3, 1]])
Q = np.array([[3,7,13,11], [19,23,31,29]])
R = np.array(['a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'f'])
S = np.array(['aacbbc', 'cabbca'])
j = 3

int_result = []  # ideally, I want this intermediate result to be a 2d NumPy array
for cat in range(len(S)):
    ind1 = np.where(X[:,1] == cat)[0]
    tmp1 = np.where(R[X[ind1][:,0]] == S[cat][3])[0]
    tmp2 = X[ind1[tmp1]]
    int_result.extend(tmp2)

result = []  # ideally, I want this to be a 2d NumPy array
for i in range(len(int_result)):
    tmp3 = [int_result[i][0], np.random.choice(Q[int_result[i][1]])]
    result.append(tmp3)
```

**Note: I only care about result, so a solution that circumvents the computation of the intermediate result would be great!**

I am hoping for a more efficient solution using NumPy that directly computes the result without many intermediate steps. Numba-based solutions do not seem to perform well on my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate and compare performances between the OP codes and newer codes, larger size inputs must be prepared. However just by expanding the `S` array using `S = np.tile(S, n)` to shape(n,), some of my benchmarks showed that the following codes will improve the performance much:

**Part1**

I think writing loops and accelerate it by numba library could improve it a lot **(~1000 times for S size 10000: 200ms --> 200us)**. I think this part consume more times than part 2, so working on that is more important:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def res1(X, R, S, j):
    result1 = []
    for cat in range(len(S)):
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            if X[i, 1] == cat:
                if R[X[i, 0]] == S[cat][j]:
                    result1.append(X[i])
    return result1
```

**Part2**

You can create a random array containing integers with appropriate shape (for column indices) at one step, then broadcast `Q` as array based on length of `result1`. Using indexing, based on the created random array, we can collect the values from each row of the broadcasted `Q` **(~3 times for S size 10000: 74 us--> 26us)**:

```
# creating a random array of integers at once instead during loops
rand_col_ids = np.random.randint(0, Q.shape[1], (len(result1)))
# [2 0 1]

# broadcasting Q and indexing to collect the values from its rows based on the created random array
ids_col = Q[np.array(result1)[:, 1]][np.arange(rand_col_ids.shape[0]), rand_col_ids]
# [13  3 23]

# creating the result2
result2 = np.array((np.array(result1)[:, 0], ids_col)).T
# [[ 2 13]
#  [ 4  3]
#  [ 3 23]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I compared your approach with mine on my desktop. For 2 categories, n = 1000 and p = 10000, my approach takes 0.7ms whereas your approach takes 4.4s. Based on prior experience, I think Numba-based solutions aren't very effective on my desktop. I've updated my question to mention this.

Comment: @sindhuja As I said, *To evaluate and compare performances between the OP codes and newer codes, larger size inputs must be prepared*, you must prepare a large example based on the needed sizes and put them here to evaluate. Performance of all proposed newer codes is depend on your input sizes. The answers will be considered based on their sizes. Here, I have just test on larger `S`, and the benchmarks are provided on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13Ksy0SCj6bBbdtrduqJallcs_eN3zz38?usp=sharing). I don't think it be related to your machine much, just to size of the inputs.

Comment: @sindhuja For an example that I tested and put in the colab, for n = 1000 and R size 10200, `result1` was slower around 5 times, but `result2` was around 25 times faster using these written codes (by these sizes, `result2` performance is the main time consumer, so it must be considered as the main goal). I think the combination of these proposed codes will be better than the ex ones both for small and large array sizes.

Comment: Did you test the runtime just once? How you test it? Check the runtime from the second run. Consider that, the numba compilation (`@nb.njit`) will take some seconds in the first run to determine the data types and the next calls of this function will be fast; This consumed compilation time in the first time, could be avoided by signatures, but it is recommended to let the numba determine them.